# How to flip camera view?

Tags: interface, camera

There is a hotkey mentioned by Gleb in the Blender Guru podcast that allows the camera view to be flipped on the x/y axis, I can't remember it for the world, nor find it anywhere in google.  The episode is like 3hs long so I'd prefer not to go through it again trying to find the moment he mentions it.  What is this hotkey?

Comment: Is this for rendering or preview?

Comment: that's a dulipcate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26208/how-to-flip-the-view-from-the-camera-horizontally

Answer (score 4):

## 3D  view/Render

Give the camera a negative scale on the local X axis.

Both <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> `-1` and <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> do this (use <kbd>Y</kbd> instead of <kbd>X</kbd> for flipping vertically), or you can set the scale directly in the transform panel:

[image]

## Rendered animation playback

When [previewing an already-rendered animation](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/output/display.html#animation-playback) (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>) you can flip the display horizontally with <kbd>F</kbd> and vertically with <kbd>Shift-F</kbd>.

## Sequencer

The VSE has an option to flip strips in *Properties region > Filter*:

[image]

---

*Thanks [ideasman42](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/55/ideasman42) for mentioning these :)*

Comment: well that's another way of doing it. I've just found the hotkey i was mentioning, Ctrl + M and then pressing the x or the y key. thanks

Comment: I accidentally reduced my scale below ZERO and was so confused until I found this post. Thank you!