# Quickly flip your camera / scene horizontally in 2.8? (like in Photoshop)

Tags: camera

I would like to be able to flip my camera / composition horizontally in Blender 2.8 quickly, without the need to render the scene and flip it in image editor.

I found other topics explaining how to use <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>-1</kbd> shortcut on the camera itself, to scale it on negative X, this way flipping the composition horizotally. However, this does not seem to work in 2.82.

Please, do you know of any quick solution for this in Blender 2.8?

Thankyou!
Martin

Comment: Hello :). It still works in 2.82. You can just type *-1* into the [Scale panel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26209/), but other methods work too.

Comment: Note: when you flip the camera X=-1, face orientation displayed through the camera is flipped. This was always the case, it's just easier to notice in newer Blender versions.

Comment: Thank you, indeed, it worked after a while of playing around with some setups. I guess only my original test did not work :-D

Comment: Happy to hear you made it work :).